# Is there a way to do in one method instead of two?

Tags: java

There are two methods, which does exactly same things, only object types are different... Is there a way to write this only with a method, combine them into 1.

method 1 :

```
private List<Car> removeSameColor(List<Car> list) {
        Set<String> colorSet = new HashSet<>();
        Iterator<Car> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if(!colorSet .isEmpty() && colorSet .contains(iterator.next().getColor())) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
            else{
                colorSet.add(iterator.next().getColor());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

this is the second method:

```
   private List<Computer> removeSameColor2(List<Computer> list) {
            Set<String> colorSet = new HashSet<>();
            Iterator<Computer> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                if(!colorSet .isEmpty() && colorSet .contains(iterator.next().getColor())) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
                else{
                    colorSet.add(iterator.next().getColor());
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: You can write your entire application in one single method, if that is what you want. that doesn't mean it improves the code, though

Comment: IntelliJ tells "dublicate found" for these two methods :( but object types are different so i am not sure how to combine them

Comment: In your case, I would read up on Generics

Comment: Start by declaring an interface for "colored objects" .....

Comment: If your `Computer` and `Car` had a common base type (such as an interface), then you could use the same method for both.

Comment: PS, your methods have a bug - calling `iterator.next()` twice in the same iteration of the loop is wrong.

Comment: Actually Car extends Computer in my case... therefore I could not even write method names same (erasure exception)

Comment: @a.solak Car extends Computer ???? that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes i actually change the names, lets say cars are kind of computers :D

Comment: it is not working removing the first method, i tried to left only with car or computer both are not working, i need 2 different methods I guess and if i want to write only in one, maybe i can check generic as discussed

Comment: If I write as generic the iterator() method is not working

Comment: Probably there is no way to combine them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Car` and `Computer` classes don't already implement a common interface, and you need to do this without modifying the classes, you can pass an additional parameter, a function to extract the `String` from the list elements:

```
private <T> List<T> removeSameColor(List<T> list, Function<? super T, String> fn) {
    Set<String> colorSet = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if(!colorSet .isEmpty() && colorSet .contains(fn.apply(iterator.next()))) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
        else{
            colorSet.add(fn.apply(iterator.next()));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

and invoke like:

```
removeSameColor(listOfCars, Car::getColour);
removeSameColor(listOfComputers, Computer::getColour);
```

Note that you are calling `iterator.next()` twice in the loop body. You probably want to store it in a variable:

```
T value = iterator.next();
if (!colorSet.isEmpty() && colorSet.contains(fn.apply(value))) {
  iterator.remove();
} else {
  colorSet.add(fn.apply(value));
}
```

In fact, you can simply store `String color = fn.apply(iterator.next())`, and then use that in place of `fn.apply(value)`.

And then you can simplify the loop further, by exploiting the return value of `Set.add`:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String color = fn.apply(iterator.next());
  if (!colorSet.add(color)) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was what i was looking for!!!

Comment: just one thing, using iterator.next() 2 times gave error, so i assigned it to a variable :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private <T extends HasColor> List<T> removeSameColor(List<T> list) {
        Set<String> colorSet = new HashSet<>();
        Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if(!colorSet .isEmpty() && colorSet .contains(iterator.next().getColor())) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
            else{
                colorSet.add(iterator.next().getColor());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Then have both `Computer` and `Car` implement a new interface, `HasColor`:

```
interface HasColor {
    String getColor();
}
```

If you're using Java 8 or above, there is a simpler alternative:

```
Set<String> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
return list.stream()
    .filter(t -> seen.add(t.getColor()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will deduplicate the list according to the distinctness of each list item's color.

Comment: "this is a much simpler alternative:" It's not, because it doesn't do the same thing, in at least 2 ways. Firstly, that this is looking at the equality of the instances, not equality of the color; there is nothing to indicate that equals/hashCode are overridden, nor that they take colour into account. Secondly, OP's code updates the `list` parameter, rather than returning a new list with the correct values.

Comment: Good catch @AndyTurner - I was mistaken. A stateful filter could be used in the stream instead to filter out duplicate colours. Re. your second point about updating the list parameter - although you're absolutely correct, given that the method is returning its own input parameter, there's nothing stopping you from just reassigning the list... e.g. `list = removeSameColor(list);` That's probably already how it's being used, given the method isn't just returning void.

Comment: "A stateful filter could be used in the stream" [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) is documented as requiring a non-stateful predicate.

Comment: That applies to parallel streams - sequential streams will be deterministic in nature. Given OP has asked for a method which returns a list consisting of the 'first' items encountered with each given colour, parallelism is out the window here. If he tried to parallelise the for loop, he'd encounter the same problem because the operation he's doing inherently relies on ordering.

Answer (score 1):

It seems both `Car` and `Computer` have a `getColor()` method. So it makes sense to pull that into an interface:

```
interface Colored {
    Color getColor();
}
```

and make both `Car` and `Computer` implement `Colored`.
Then you can write your one method as

```
private <T extends Colored> List<T> removeSameColor(List<T> list) {
        Set<String> colorSet = new HashSet<>();
        Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if(!colorSet .isEmpty() && colorSet .contains(iterator.next().getColor())) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
            else{
                colorSet.add(iterator.next().getColor());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```